# Crystal Report using XSD File as source doesn't show data?

Tags: vb.net, xsd, crystal-reports, datasource

I have a Crystal Report file I've created, using an .XSD file as the data source. As far as creation goes it's great, no problem. I can see the table and all the fields from it. I can drag them off the data explorer and onto the report.

The problem is when I go to preview or use the report. There's no data. Trying to browse the data in the data explorer? No data. But if I browse the XSD from within visual Studio, it shows me the data just fine.

Why am I not seeing any data from this report with an XSD as datasource?

Craig

Comment: XSD is a schema. It doesn't contain any data. If you want to show data in your report, you must set its datasource to a datatable like this. yourReport.SetDataSource(your_DataTable_That_Has_The_Same_Schema_As_The_XSD_You_Used_In_Your_Design). Then display the report in CrystalReportViewer

Comment: Actually that makes sense, thanks.